# Getting ProtocolException with running DotNetOpenAuth sample

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I have downloaded DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.6.10357 built it (had to exclude `OpenIdOfflineProvider` because of build errors) and run `OAuthConsumerWpf`. After clicking `Authorize` I got the exception below. Please bear in mind I modified `app.config` as instructed. This is from the `Google` tab. I also tried `Generic` tab with the same results.

What could be wrong here? Shouldn't things as simple as this work out of the box?

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException was unhandled
    Message=Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
    Source=DotNetOpenAuth
    StackTrace:
        at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\StandardWebRequestHandler.cs:line 172
        at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\StandardWebRequestHandler.cs:line 100
        at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.GetDirectResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 607
        at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage request) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 628
        at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 451
        at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request[TResponse](IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:line 431
        at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ConsumerBase.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(Uri callback, IDictionary`2 requestParameters, IDictionary`2 redirectParameters, String& requestToken) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ConsumerBase.cs:line 222
        at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.DesktopConsumer.RequestUserAuthorization(IDictionary`2 requestParameters, IDictionary`2 redirectParameters, String& requestToken) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\DesktopConsumer.cs:line 42
        at DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.GoogleConsumer.RequestAuthorization(DesktopConsumer consumer, Applications requestedAccessScope, String& requestToken) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.6.10357\Samples\DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock\GoogleConsumer.cs:line 204
        at DotNetOpenAuth.Samples.OAuthConsumerWpf.MainWindow.<beginAuthorizationButton_Click>b__3(DesktopConsumer consumer, String& requestToken) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.6.10357\Samples\OAuthConsumerWpf\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 92
        at DotNetOpenAuth.Samples.OAuthConsumerWpf.Authorize.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__0(Object state) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.6.10357\Samples\OAuthConsumerWpf\Authorize.xaml.cs:line 33
        at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
        at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
    InnerException: System.Net.WebException
        Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
        Source=System
        StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options) in c:\Users\andarno\git\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\StandardWebRequestHandler.cs:line 126
        InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  Perhaps your computer is behind a firewall or needs a proxy server registered?

Comment: I do have a Windows firewall (allows all outbound connections). I am also behind a NAT router. Other than this I use no proxies. I am connecting directly. What else could be the issue?